# easySlider slide briefly gets "shot out" or "flashes" out of container when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, easyslider

The following code is what I have in my site's general scripts.js file. I am using EasySlider as a JavaScript image slider and when the page loads, I am noticing that one of the image slides shoots out of the image slider or another way of describing it is it flashes on the screen and then returns back to the slider. Any ideas what this could be? Let me know if this isn't enough information to help diagnose the issue and I will provide more code.

```
            /* 10. Featured Content Slider */
            #prevBtn, #nextBtn, #slider1prev, #slider1next {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                display: block;
                overflow: hidden;
                /*text-indent: -8000px;*/
            }
            #prevBtn {
                background: url('images/left-arrow.png') no-repeat;
                width: 44px;
                height: 73px;
                    float: left;
                top: 300px;
                z-index: 10000;
            }
            #nextBtn {
                background: url('images/right-arrow.png') no-repeat;
                width: 44px;
                height: 73px;
                float: right;
                top: 100px;
            }
            .left-panel {
                background-color: #000000;
                opacity: .8;
                width: 100%;
                height: 470px;
                z-index: 800;
                position: absolute;
                border-right: 1px solid #000000;
            }
            .right-panel {
                background-color: #000000;
                opacity: .8;
                width: 100%;
                height: 470px;
                z-index: 800;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                border-left: 1px solid #000000;
            }
            #container {
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #555555;
            }
            #content {
                position: relative;
                top: 64px;
            }

            #slider {
                padding: 0px 0px 64px 0px;
                display: block;
                height: 100% !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            #slider li {
                position: relative;
                width: 696px;
                height: 241;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #slider li img {
                /*position:absolute;*/
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #slider li a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            #slider ul, #slider li,
            #slider2 ul, #slider2 li {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style: none;
            }
            #slider2 {
                margin-top: 1em;
            }
            #slider li, #slider2 li {
                width: 940px;
                height: 400px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #prevBtn, #nextBtn,
            #slider1next, #slider1prev {
                display: block;
                width: 30px;
                height: 77px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 71px;
                z-index: 1000;
            }
            #nextBtn, #slider1next {
                right: 0;
            }
            #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a,
            #slider1next a, #slider1prev a {
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                width: 30px;
                height: 77px;
                background: url(../images/btn_prev.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
            #nextBtn a, #slider1next a {
                background: url(../images/btn_next.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
            }
            ol#controls {
                margin: 1em 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 28px;
            }
            ol#controls li {
                margin: 0 10px 0 0;
                padding: 0;
                float: left;
                list-style: none;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
            }
            ol#controls li a {
                float: left;
                height: 28px;
                line-height: 28px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background: #DAF3F8;
                color: #555;
                padding: 0 10px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            ol#controls li.current a {
                background: #5DC9E1;
                color: #fff;
            }
            ol#controls li a:focus, #prevBtn a:focus, #nextBtn a:focus {
                outline: none;
            }
            .featured-content-slider-title {
                font-family: Museo;
                color: #2e2e2e;
                font-size: 20px;
                position: absolute;
                max-width: 830px;
                left: 10px;
                bottom: 65px;
                padding: 6px 10px;
                left: 30px;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .featured-content-slider-author {
                font-family: Museo;
                color: #2e2e2e;
                font-size: 14px;
                position: absolute;
                left: 10px;
                bottom: 30px;
                padding: 6px 10px;
                left: 30px;
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
            }
            .border {
                background: url('images/cta-border-top.png') repeat-x;
                width: 100%;
                height: 24px;
                margin-top: -7px;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 500;
            }
            <!-- Container -->
            <div id="container">

                <!-- Content -->
                <div id="content">

                    <span class="left-panel"></span>

                    <span class="right-panel"></span>

                    <!-- Slider -->
                    <div id="slider">

                        <!-- Slider List -->
                        <ul>

                            <!-- Slide 1 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slide6.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-title">"I want to put a ding in the Universe."</p>
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-author">By <span class="pink">Steve Jobs</span> / 02.25.1955</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- /Slide 1 -->

                            <!-- Slide 2 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slide7.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-title">"Innotvation distinguishes between a leader and a follower."</p>
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-author">By <span class="pink">Steve Jobs</span> / 01.09.2007</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- /Slide 2 -->

                            <!-- Slide 3 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slide8.jpg" alt="" />
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-title">"It's really hard to design products by focus groups. A lot of times, people don't know what they want until you show it to them."</p>
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-author">By <span class="pink">Steve Jobs</span> / 09.14.1984</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>   
                            <!-- /Slide 3 -->

                            <!-- Slide 4 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slide1.png" alt="" />
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-title">"Your time is limited, so don't waste it living in someone else's life."</p>
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-author">By <span class="pink">Steve Jobs</span> / 03.22.1986</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- /Slide 4 -->

                            <!-- Slide 5 -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/slide3.png" alt="" />
                                <p class="featured-content-slider-title">"An iPod, a phone, an internet mobile communicator... these are NOT three separate devices! And we are calling it iPhone! Today Apple is going to reinvent the phone. And here it is."</p>
                                    <p class="featured-content-slider-author">By <span class="pink">Steve Jobs</span> / 10.05.2011</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- /Slide 5 -->

                        </ul>
                        <!-- /Slider List -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /Slider -->

                </div>
                <!-- /Content -->

            </div>
            <!-- /Container -->

            <div class="border"></div>

                            //Dynamically center featured content slide
            var image_width = 940;

            $(document).ready(function() {        
                $('#slider').css('padding-left', ($(window).width() - image_width) / 2);
            });

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $('#slider').css('padding-left', ($(window).width() - image_width) / 2);
            });

            // Dyanmically resize featured content slide left and right panels
            jQuery(window).load(function() {

                // Before window loads, resize left and right featured content slider pannels 
                var browser_width = jQuery(window).width();
                var slide_width = 940;
                var panel_width = ((browser_width-slide_width)/2);
                jQuery(".left-panel").width(panel_width);
                jQuery(".right-panel").width(panel_width);

            });

            // Document Ready
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {

                // Blockquote
                jQuery('blockquote').prepend('<div class="quote"></div>');

                // FAQ
                jQuery('.faq-question').click(function () {
                    jQuery(this).next().toggle();
                });

                //Publish Your Work Signup
                jQuery('.writingsample').click(function () {
                    jQuery(this).val("http://");
                });

                //Navigation Search
                // jQuery('.navigation-search').hover(function () {
                //  jQuery('.search-form').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                //      jQuery('input#s').mouseout(function() {
                //          jQuery(this).fadeOut();
                //      });
                //  });
                // });

                jQuery('.navigation-search').click(function () {
                    jQuery('.search-form').toggle();
                });

                // Search Results
                jQuery('#search-results').keyup(function () {
                        var search = jQuery('#search-results').val();
                    jQuery('.search-feedback').html(search);
                });

                //Floating search result sidebar On Other News
                $(function() {
                    var $sidebar   = $('.search-results-sidebar'), 
                        $window    = $(window),
                        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                        topPadding = 15;
                    $window.scroll(function() {
                        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                            });
                        } else {
                            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                                marginTop: 0
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });

                // Resize Featured Content Slider
                var TTB = {
                    resize:function() {
                        jQuery(".left-panel").width((jQuery(document).width()-940)/2);
                        jQuery(".left-panel a").width((jQuery(document).width()-940)/2);
                        jQuery(".right-panel").width((jQuery(document).width()-940)/2);
                        jQuery(".right-panel a").width((jQuery(document).width()-940)/2);
                    }
                }

                // Call Resize  
                jQuery(window).resize(function() {
                        TTB.resize();
                });

                // Featured Content Slider (EasySlider)
                jQuery("#slider").easySlider({
                    auto:           true, 
                    continuous:     true,
                    prevId:         'featured-content-slider-left-panel',
                    prevText:       '',
                    nextId:         'featured-content-slider-right-panel',  
                    nextText:       '',
                    controlsShow:   true,
                    controlsBefore: '',
                    controlsAfter:  '', 
                    controlsFade:   true,
                    firstId:        'firstBtn',
                    firstText:      'First',
                    firstShow:      false,
                    lastId:         'lastBtn',  
                    lastText:       'Last',
                    lastShow:       false,              
                    vertical:       false,
                    speed:          3200,
                    pause:          5000,
                    numeric:        false,
                    numericId:      'controls'
              });

            });
```

Comment: A HTML sample would be great (CSS also!) cause it reminds me to an issue caused with calculating the slider width missed by some browsers (FF) due to resized images that have cumulated widths by float numbers . Cannot tell until I see a sample.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - please see above. I attached  HTML, CSS, and JS (I actually posted the full JS from my site in case something else is conflicting here) that pertains to the slider. Let me know if this is sufficient?